# CNContact :migration from ABAddressBook : iOSLegacyIdentifier + lastModifcationDate

Tags: objective-c, swift, contacts, ios9, abaddressbook

i have a DB that stores all local user contacts.
now i want to use the new framework (contact framework), my problem is that the CNContact have a new identifier now (no longer the auto-incretntal one) called "identifier" and i can't mach old entries in my DB with a potential update of a contact.

i have 2 questions:

1. in xcode debugger, i can see _iOSLegacyIdentifier(the old, auto-incremental one) as a property in CNContact, how can i get it without private API calls
2. i can't see "lastModifcationDate" for the CNContact (in ABAddressBook framework it is called kABPersonModificationDateProperty) how can i get it using the new framework.

thanks.

[EDIT]: i have open a ticket for Apple about this and here's the answer:

> There are no plans to address this based on the following:
>
> 1) iOSLegacyIdentifier is private API for CNContact. 2) A modification
>   date is not offered on CNContact.
>
> To migrate your DB you can to match contacts by name and disambiguate
>   by manually matching other properties like email addresses or phone
>   numbers.
>
> We are now closing this report.

as you can see there's no real solution for this, we have to guess..

Comment: Also interested in this. There must be a way to migrate these contact ID's we have stored...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1.Doesn't exists. There is only private selector

```
[CNContact iOSLegacyIdentifier];
```

or you can get the same

```
[CNContainer CNContainerIOSLegacyIdentifierKey];
```

Mind that this is not compiled in framework. Use perform selector

2.There is no such property in the new framework. If you disassembly the Contact framework you can see that uniqueId is still used in predicates that touches underlaying core data. But that's a work for you and again dance with private selectors

(blame Apple, not me that there is no way). Take a look at internals of the framework.

Comment: Be happy that it works on iOS. On OS X the Contacts framework can't even display contact.

Comment: i can't use private APIs, have anyone submit an app containing the call  of iOSLegacyIdentifier ?

Comment: Private APIs are being used by developers. It's the matter of masking what you do and not being caught. Also make 1000% sure that your code will not crash with the disappearance of private API. You have options: 1)Use TSI and ask Apple how to do it 2)Hope that god will appear here and tell you magic API or workaround 3)Disassemble framework and find magic API 4)Exclude functionality. 5)Use private API; Clocks are ticking -> that's the biggest enemy here.

Comment: i opened a bug in bugreport #22895795, let see what they will answer.

Comment: I opened several of them this year in August. Till now they haven't even looked at it. Good luck.

Comment: last question: if i use the Xcode validation before uploading to the store and the validation pass, can i be sure that my app will not be rejected using what you suggest ?

Comment: You cannot simply use private API. You have to obfuscate your calls. If you don't -> reject. Mind that they use static analysis (not runtime). I can't tell you more tricks.

Answer (score 1):

you can obtain ContactID (iOSLegacyIdentifier) with new Contact Framework. I use this in my app to find iOSLegacyIdentifier for specific contact, you can modify for your pleasure.

```
let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContacts(matchingName: "contactName")
        let toFetch = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactIdentifierKey]

        do{
            let contacts = try self.contactStore.unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch: toFetch as [CNKeyDescriptor])

            for contact in contacts{
                var diccionario:[String : Any] = contact.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys: ["iOSLegacyIdentifier"])
                //With this you can see/obtain iOSLegacyIdentifier
                print(diccionario["iOSLegacyIdentifier"] as! Int)
                return;
            }
        } catch let err{
            print(err)
        }
```